# Confused with array_filter ignoring 0 values even if explicitly checking

Tags: php

I don't understand why this is returning an empty array for me.

```
$fruits = [
    'apple' => 3,
    'pear' => 5,
    'orange' => 0
];

$filtered = array_filter($fruits, function($fruit) {
    if ($fruit == 0) {
        return $fruit;
    }
});

var_dump($filtered); //array (size=0)
```

The callback function evaluates to true for 'orange' but still the array is empty. If I do it for any of the other ones specifically then it returns correctly.

```
$fruits = [
    'apple' => 3,
    'pear' => 5,
    'orange' => 0
];

$filtered = array_filter($fruits, function($fruit) {
    if ($fruit == 5) {
        return $fruit;
    }
});

var_dump($filtered); 
// array (size=1) 
// 'pear' => int 5
```

Comment: array_filter's callback has to return `true`, not `$fruit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`array_filter()` expects `true` to include an element and `false` to exclude it. You are saying if `$fruit == 0` then return `0`, and if not then don't return anything.  The result of a function that doesn't return anything is `null` and both `0` and `null` evaluate loosely to `false`, so it is always `false`:

```
if ($fruit == 0) {
    return $fruit;
}
```

At a minimum, you want to check for NOT `0` and return true:

```
if ($fruit !== 0) {
    return true;
}
```

Or to be verbose:

```
if ($fruit === 0) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

If you're OK with filtering out `0`, `false`, `null` and an empty string `""` then you can just use:

```
$filtered = array_filter($fruits);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try return $fruit === 0 instead of return the $fruit. Like follow:

```
$filtered = array_filter($fruits, function($fruit) {
  return $fruit === 0;
});
```